# python - Parallel sys.std.isatty()

Tags: python, mpi, stdout

I'm using the top answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python) question to print my output to colour, but when running on HPC this kind of output isn't supported. The suggested workaround seems to be to use `sys.stdout.isatty()` to determine where the output is being directed and remove the unicode colouring.

However when I run my code in parallel (with `$ mpirun -n 2 python foo.py > output.txt`) it no longer returns the expected bool (i.e. it returns True when in serial it returned False). Even if I do a mpi rank check before it eg:

```
if MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank() == 0:  print sys.stdout.isatty()
```

Am I misunderstanding the way this function is supposed to work and/or is there an alternate way to determine the direction of the output when running in parallel?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: It looks like `mpirun` creates pseudo-ttys for its children.

Comment: Why not just add a command-line flag to disable colored output?